# iOS 5 Safari and the IFRAME element

Tags: css, iframe, mobile-safari, ios5

Where can I find documentation about the new behavior of the IFRAME element in iOS 5 Safari?  Empirical evidence suggests that IFRAMEs now will expand to fit the content, expanding the containing document to do so, thereby often breaking code that works fine in iOS4.3 (and desktop browsers).

Is there any way to control this new behavior?

Comment: Have you tried applying styles directly to the IFRAME to control its behavior?

Comment: yes - it does not help.  There is a definite shift in behavior between iOS4 and iOS5.  Seems to me Apple chose the worst way to solve the two-finger scroll problem with iframed content.  Sigh.

Comment: So, what do you do now? -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but is this related to my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299897/safari-mobile-iframe-with-inner-iframe-size-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any official documentation that lists the differences of the `<iframe>` tag in iOS5, but I found these links which do explain a little bit about the new `<iframe>` tag/changes in iOS5 safari.

[New Mobile Safari stuff in iOS5](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5)

[iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 5.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010949)

[Handling Events, Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

You mentioned that the `<iframe>` tag now stretches to the width of the content inside it. Would you want it to be a set width?

You could either...

1. Try styling the `iframe` in css to the width you want it (I'm sure you've tried this)
2. Set a width to the `body` tag so that the `iframe` doesn't stretch outside of it (not sure if this works)
3. Put a `<div>` around the content being retrieved by the `iframe` that has a set width

**Edit:** I just read the comment saying to style the `iframe` directly, but you mentioned it doesn't work. I'd try styling the container `div` instead, if that's an option.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, but none of the links seem to apply and the workarounds  were tried prior to posting the question.

Comment: The links do apply. You asked for documentation about the changes to the `iframe` element. Link 1 says "For content that doesn’t fit in its container element, previously the content was completely cut off (similarly with frames)". Link 2 was put there to show that there was no apple documentation. As for my solutions, #3 should work and I noted that #1 was already covered.