# Safari Mobile iframe with inner iframe size problems

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, ios5, mobile-safari

I have a "simple" web application that has a navigation and a content area. 
Within the content area I have a iframe with more complex content. Unfortunately the content in the iframe has another iframe.

The get an overview look here:

[image: Initial view].

In my scenario it is quite helpful to see the full iframe content, so we hide the navigation and change the content size on top of it:

[image: Fullscreen view]

If I go back now to initial view the iframe inside the iframe doesn't change the size:

[image]

This happend only on Safari mobile (iPad) OS 5.1. On normal Safari browser it works as expected. 
Does anyone have a similar problem or an idea what is happening here?

Of course a solution would be even better :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is an issue that only occurs in Safari or iPad you could add some cross-browser CSS support to tell the specific browser how it should appear. I like using [this one](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

This allows you to add specific css instructions such as

.[os].[browser] .mylink { font-weight: bold; } -> without space between .[os] and .[browser]

.iphone.safari .scrollingframe {css style}

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that your are not allowed to change the inner iframe content in due to cross browser restriction. I think there is no solution for that kind of problem...